# How do I create and complete a play.libs.F.Promise?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, promise

I'd like to create a `play.libs.F.Promise` from a call to an async third-party service so I can chain the call and return a `Promise<Result>` instead of blocking inside the controller. Something like so:

```java
final Promise<String> promise = new Promise();
service.execute(new Handler() {
  public void onSuccess(String result) {
    promise.complete(result);
  }
})
return promise;
```

Unfortunately, there does not appear to be a way to create an empty `play.libs.F.Promise`, and there is no method to complete a promise, either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a [F.RedeemablePromise](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/java/play/libs/F.RedeemablePromise.html).

```
RedeemablePromise<String> promise = RedeemablePromise.empty();

promise.map(string ->
  // This would apply once the redeemable promise succeed
  ok(string + " World!")
);

// In another thread, you now may complete the RedeemablePromise.
promise.success("Hello");

// OR you can fail the promise
promise.failure(new Exception("Problem"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the current version of play and the [play.libs.F.Promise](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/api/java/play/libs/F.Promise.html), a promise can be created in two ways: 1) Using a scala Future and Callback or 2) using a [play Function0](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/JavaAsync) (replace A for any class):

```
import static akka.dispatch.Futures.future;
//Using 1)
Promise<A> promise=Promise.wrap(future(
    new Callable<A>() {
        public A call() {
        //Do whatever
        return new A();
  }
}, Akka.system().dispatcher()));

//Using 2) - This is described in the Play 2.2.1 Documentation
// http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/JavaAsync 
Promise<A> promise2= Promise.promise(
  new Function0<A>() {
    public A apply() {
        //Do whatever
        return new A();
    }
  }
);
```

---

**EDIT:** When you can't modify the async block because it's provided by a third party you can use the approach of creating an empty Promise ([scala promise](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html), not play framework promise). Then you can use the Future containing the scala Promise to generate a play.libs.F.Promise as follows:

```
import akka.dispatch.Futures;

final scala.concurrent.Promise<String> promise = Futures.promise();
service.execute(new Handler() {
    public void onSuccess(String result) {
        promise.success(result);
    }
})
return Promise.wrap(promise.future());
```

Comment: The `service` is provided by a third-party, as mentioned above, and it's async, too. So how do I create a Promise that can be completed in the callback passed to the service?

Comment: Check at my Edit in the main comment. It should work like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can return empty promise by doing the following:

```
return F.Promise.pure(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create F.Promise like this:

```
F.Promise<User> userPromise = F.Promise.promise(() -> getUserFromDb());
```

and use its value when it is ready:

```
userPromise.onRedeem(user -> showUserData(user));
```